# Balanced subsets

Tags: combinatorics, contest-math

> Define $S_n$ as the set ${1,2,\cdots,n}$. A non-empty subset $T_n$ of
>   $S_n$ is called $balanced$ if the average of the elements of $T_n$ is
>   equal to the median of $T_n$. Prove that, for all $n$, the number of
>   balanced subsets $T_n$ is odd.

Set up a 1-1 correspondence of unbalanced subsets using complements! Lends itself to an instant solution

Is there another solution?

Comment: There are always hard ways to prove anything. Since you've found the easy way, why are you looking for harder ones?

Comment: One that is only slightly harder is to instead pair every set $T_n$ with a different "complement": $\{n + 1 - t\mid t \in T_n\}$. One has to note that there $2*n - 1$ non-empty subsets and every set which is its own "complement" is balanced.

Comment: @PaulSinclair I like to understand other types of solutions.

Comment: @PaulSinclair I believe you are using the same "complement" as OP. E,g with $n=4$, the only unbalanced subsets are $\{1, 2, 4\}, \{1, 3, 4\}$.

Comment: @CalvinLin - If that is the case, then I'll suggest the type of complement I think Tortugut is referring to: set complementation. Pair $T_n$ with $S_n\setminus T_n$. You just need to show that $T_n$ is balanced if and only if $S_n\setminus T_n$ is, and that $S_n$ itself (the only one without a complement, since $\emptyset$ is disallowed) is balanced. (I see that in my previous comment, i accidently entered "*" instead of "^" and failed to notice - there are $2^n - 1$ non-empty subsets.)

Comment: My point was that set complements do not work. IE $\{3\}$ is balanced but $\{1, 2, 4\}$ is not, and $\{1,2\}, \{3,4\}$ are balanced set complements. The best approach I had was to do the $n+1 - t$ pairing, and then account for self-complements, which didn't seem obvious to me.